# How to display plot clicks on a plot in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I would like users to be able to click on a plot, and when they do record leave a mark or a message at that the point they clicked.

I am using reactive values within the plotting environment. This seems to be resetting the plot. Almost immediately after the message appears.

Here is a minimum not-fully-working example

```
library(shiny)

## ui.R
ui <- fluidPage(
    shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
    column(12,
        plotOutput("Locations", width=500, height=500,
            click="plot_click") )
)


## server.R
server <- function( input, output, session){


    ## Source Locations (Home Base)
    source_coords <- reactiveValues(xy=c(x=1, y=2) )

    ## Dest Coords
    dest_coords <- reactive({
        if (is.null(input$plot_click) ){
            list( x=source_coords$xy[1],
                  y=source_coords$xy[2])
        }  else {
            list( x=floor(input$plot_click$x),
                  y=floor(input$plot_click$y))
        }
    })


    ## Calculate Manhattan Distance from Source to Destination
    DistCost <- reactive({
        list( Lost=sum( abs(
            c(dest_coords()$x, dest_coords()$y) - source_coords$xy
        ) ) )
    })


    ## RenderPlot 
    output$Locations <- renderPlot({ 

        par(bg=NA)
        plot.new()
        plot.window(
            xlim=c(0,10), ylim=c(0,10),
            yaxs="i", xaxs="i")
        axis(1)
        axis(2)
        grid(10,10, col="black")
        box()

        ## Source
        points( source_coords$xy[1], source_coords$xy[2], cex=3, pch=intToUtf8(8962)) 

        ## Destination
        text(dest_coords()$x, dest_coords()$y, paste0("Distance=", DistCost() ))
    })        
}




### Run Application
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `input$plot_click` flushes itself immediately after it gets values from user click, and returns to `NULL`. You can test if by yourself by creating empty list `stored <- list()`, and after that add

```
 stored[[length(stored)+1]] <<- as.character(c(input$plot_click$x, input$plot_click$y))
```

inside your dest_coords reactive. You can see that if you click the plot just once it will store three values. First is `NULL`, second is the clicked point coordinates, but there will be also the third one, which is `NULL` again. So it will flush its values away immediately after pushing them to reactives which are dependent at him. But the reactives will also take dependency at any change in the input, even if it is `NULL`. The way around this is to use `eventReactive` or `observeEvent` and make sure that `ignoreNULL` parameter is set to `TRUE` (it is actually set to `TRUE` by default). To make it work for your app, you should already store all the minimum values required to create your plot in `reactiveValues`, and after the click is made just overwrite data with those provided by `input$plot_click`.

Here is my modified example:

```
library(shiny)

## ui.R
ui <- fluidPage(
  shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
  column(12,
         plotOutput("Locations", width=500, height=500,
                    click="plot_click"))
)


## server.R
server <- function( input, output, session){

  source_coords <- reactiveValues(xy=data.frame(x=c(1,1),  y=c(1,1)))

  observeEvent(input$plot_click, {
    source_coords$xy[2,] <- c(input$plot_click$x, input$plot_click$y)
    })

  ## RenderPlot 
  output$Locations <- renderPlot({ 
    par(bg=NA)
    plot.new()
    plot.window(
      xlim=c(0,10), ylim=c(0,10),
      yaxs="i", xaxs="i")
    axis(1)
    axis(2)
    grid(10,10, col="black")
    box()

    ## Source
    points( source_coords$xy[1,1], source_coords$xy[1,2], cex=3, pch=intToUtf8(8962)) 

    ## Destination
    text(source_coords$xy[2,1], source_coords$xy[2,2], paste0("Distance=", sum(abs(source_coords$xy[1,]-source_coords$xy[2,]))))
  })        

}

### Run Application
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: And just one additional note. You should avoid this kind of reactive structure, where there is some C which is reactively dependent on A and B, and at the same time B is reactively dependent on A. Because there is always a chance that C will run its code reactively because of the change in A, and it will break because B just won't make it before C needs B. You should always put B inside C or merge A and B into one reactive. Its safer.

Comment: Which reactive structure are you saying I should avoid - your answer or my original post. If you mean your answer, could you show me what would be better.

Comment: Oh sorry, I was refering to your original post. Your dest_coords was one reactive, after that DistCost was another reactive which was dependent on dest_coords, so on any change in dest_coords it would reevaluate its code, and finally your plot was reactively dependent on both of them: dest_coords and DistCost. So your plot is C, DistCost is B and dest_coords is A in my example. Sorry for not being explicit with that example.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure if the intent was to only show the most recently clicked point, or to show all the points clicked. Since the answer by Pawel covers the former case (and is already an accepted answer, which means it probably was the intent), I'll post a solution to the former, for future reference in case it helps anymore

```
library(magrittr)
library(shiny)

## ui.R
ui <- fluidPage(
    shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
    column(12,
        plotOutput("Locations", width=500, height=500,
            click="plot_click") )
)


## server.R
server <- function( input, output, session){

    initX <- 1
    initY <- 2

    ## Source Locations (Home Base)
    source_coords <- reactiveValues(xy=c(x=initX, y=initY) )

    ## Dest Coords
    dest_coords <- reactiveValues(x=initX, y=initY)
    observeEvent(plot_click_slow(), {
      dest_coords$x <- c(dest_coords$x, floor(plot_click_slow()$x))
      dest_coords$y <- c(dest_coords$y, floor(plot_click_slow()$y))
    })

    ## Don't fire off the plot click too often
    plot_click_slow <- debounce(reactive(input$plot_click), 300)

    ## Calculate Manhattan Distance from Source to Destination
    DistCost <- reactive({
        num_points <- length(dest_coords$x)

        list( Lost= lapply(seq(num_points), function(n) {
          sum( abs(
            c(dest_coords$x[n], dest_coords$y[n]) - source_coords$xy
          ) )
        }) )
    })


    ## RenderPlot
    output$Locations <- renderPlot({

        par(bg=NA)
        plot.new()
        plot.window(
            xlim=c(0,10), ylim=c(0,10),
            yaxs="i", xaxs="i")
        axis(1)
        axis(2)
        grid(10,10, col="black")
        box()

        ## Source
        points( source_coords$xy[1], source_coords$xy[2], cex=3, pch=intToUtf8(8962))

        ## Destination
        text(dest_coords$x, dest_coords$y, paste0("Distance=", DistCost()$Lost ))
    })
}




### Run Application
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Could you plz clarify why you use `debounce()` here or what exactly you mean by "Not to fire off the plot click too often"? Thx

Comment: You can look up the function documentation for `shiny::debounce()` or if you're not sure what it does